# How to extract metadata from BIM 360 model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

How can I extract metadata from a model that sits in BIM360?

I can extract the metadata by uploading Revit file and translate it to svf. I used GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties endpoint to extract the data.

How can I do that from a model in BIM360?
Any suggestions or guidance please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to work with BIM 360 data, the first is [Get Access to a BIM 360 Account] and [Manage API Access to BIM 360 Services]. The papers below tell in detail:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/get-access-to-account/
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/manage-access-to-docs/

Next, I would suggest you may get started with the tutorial on how to get models from SaaS products of Autodesk such as BIM 360 Docs. It demos the workflow step by step:
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels

After getting access to the model, you could get metadata without explicitly sending model to translate because BIM 360 will translate the source file to SVF by default. Another sample would be of use for your reference:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-derivatives-explorer

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Actually, what I want to extract from the metadata are element data like "External ID", "GUID", "Category", can we get those data kind of data also? Because I can't see it in derivatives.autodesk.io model.

Comment: yes, these data is available with :urn/metadata/:guid/properties. derivatives.autodesk.io dumps the data, but only displays sub-properties, while External ID locates in properties of first level. This snapshot shows https://snipboard.io/dhJHBr.jpg

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I have managed to get all the properties I need.